# Javascript Nested Classes

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, inheritance

Are there any potential issues with the following Javascript code:

```
var BobsGarage = BobsGarage || {}; // namespace

/**
 * BobsGarage.Car
 * @constructor
 * @returns {BobsGarage.Car}
 */
BobsGarage.Car = function() {

    /**
     * Engine
     * @constructor
     * @returns {Engine}
     */
    var Engine = function() {
        // definition of an engine
    };

    Engine.prototype.constructor = Engine;
    Engine.prototype.start = function() {
        console.log('start engine');
    };

    /**
     * Tank
     * @constructor
     * @returns {Tank}
     */
    var Tank = function() {
        // definition of a tank
    };

    Tank.prototype.constructor = Tank;
    Tank.prototype.fill = function() {
        console.log('fill tank');
    };

    this.engine = new Engine();
    this.tank = new Tank();
};

BobsGarage.Car.prototype.constructor = BobsGarage.Car;

/**
 * BobsGarage.Ferrari
 * Derived from BobsGarage.Car
 * @constructor
 * @returns {BobsGarage.Ferrari}
 */
BobsGarage.Ferrari = function() {
    BobsGarage.Car.call(this);
};
BobsGarage.Ferrari.prototype = Object.create(BobsGarage.Car.prototype);
BobsGarage.Ferrari.prototype.constructor = BobsGarage.Ferrari;
BobsGarage.Ferrari.prototype.speedUp = function() {
    console.log('speed up');
};

// Test it on the road

var car = new BobsGarage.Car();
car.tank.fill();
car.engine.start();

var ferrari = new BobsGarage.Ferrari();
ferrari.tank.fill();
ferrari.engine.start();
ferrari.speedUp();

// var engine = new Engine(); // ReferenceError

console.log(ferrari);
```

The goal is to have prototype inheritance and nested classes so that classes defined within `BobsGarage.Car` are not accessible outside the constructor of `BobsGarage.Car` but instances of them are accessible to derived classes, as shown in the test code.

Note: I am referring to the concept of *Class* in Javascript as defined on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any issues with your code.

One suggestion would be to make your code a little DRYer by assigning to your prototype in 1 go and drop the jsdoc ( it adds a lot of lines, for little value ).

```
//Definition of an engine
var Engine = function() {};

Engine.prototype = {
  constructor : Engine,
  start : function() {
    console.log('start engine');
  }
};
```

Instead of

```
/**
 * Engine
 * @constructor
 * @returns {Engine}
 */
var Engine = function() {
    // definition of an engine
};

Engine.prototype.constructor = Engine;
Engine.prototype.start = function() {
    console.log('start engine');
};
```

Creating `ferrari` out of `car` is even more verbose, I would suggest 2 helper functions to keep the code more readable.

```
BobsGarage.Ferrari.prototype = {
  constructor : BobsGarage.Ferrari,
  speedUp : function() {
    console.log('speed up');
  },
}

extendPrototype( BobsGarage.Car , BobsGarage.Ferrari );

function extendPrototype( base , extension )
{
  extension.prototype = extend( base.prototype , extension.prototype );
}

function extend( o , extension )
{
  for( var key in extension )
    o[key] = extension[key];
  return o;
}
```

Obviously you would keep re-using `extend` and `extendPrototype`.

Comment: Vary good suggestion, thanks. The only thing I think needs to be changed is the implementation of `extendPrototype`. The way it is implemented now also extends the base prototype, effectively assigning all extension properties to the base prototype. This can be avoided creating a new temporary object from the base prototype like this: `var klass = function() {}; klass.prototype = new base(); extension.prototype = extend(klass.prototype, extension.prototype);`.

Comment: You are right, not sure how that got past my test ;)